# Tagging Jira issues with Zapier (Hiding credentials in zapier Python)

Tags: python, zapier

We have Jira authenticated to Zapier, but it does not have tagging functionality, so I hacked up a simple python module below. However, it doesn't seem that I can reuse the already authenticated Jira account. Is there a way to hide the password somehow so it's not just clear text?

```
# jira_label and jira_url come from upstream zaps

# declaring output hash with defaults set
output = {'jira_label': jira_label}

### Python code
import requests

user  = 'my_personal_user'
dpass = 'xxx' # <--- gotta do something about it
url1   = jira_url
pdata = '{"fields": {"labels": ["' + jira_label +'"]}}'
header1 = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.put(url2, auth=(user, dpass), data=pdata, headers=header1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use, Base64 encoding :

```
    >>> import base64
    >>> print base64.b64encode("mypassword")
    bXlwYXNzd29yZA==
    >>> print base64.b64decode("bXlwYXNzd29yZA==")
    mypassword
```

With this your request will look like this:

`r = requests.put(url2, auth=(user, base64.b64decode("bXlwYXNzd29yZA==")), data=pdata, headers=header1)`

Comment: Yup, i saw that, however base64 is just an abstraction, it's the same clear text that can be reverted without any effort.